# Mysql: How do I order groups without losing individuals rows within groups

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am on phpmyadmin, and I have data:

```
query url score  
a www.google.com 3  
a www.facebook.com 2  
a www.google.com 1
```

I want to 'group' entries by their domain, and then order (desc) the domain groups by each group's highest score (some in the comments have found this wording clearer: 'order desc by each group's highest score') so I get:

```
query url score  
a www.google.com 3  
a www.google.com 1
a www.facebook.com 2
```

Trying: select * from table order by score desc, url asc doesnt work. It gives (no apparent change):

```
query url score  
a www.google.com 3  
a www.facebook.com 2  
a www.google.com 1
```

I'm apparently not communicating my troubles clearly. If you can see where I can make it clearer, let me know.

For reference, I have re-posed the question here and it has an accepted answer: [How do I order groups by each group's highest value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63193038/how-do-i-order-groups-by-each-groups-highest-value)

Comment: remove the group by?...

Comment: You don’t want to _group_, you want to _sort_. (GROUP BY condenses multiple records that match the grouping criteria, into a single one - absolutely _not_ what you want here.)

Comment: Why do you need the GROUp anyway, loose it and you can do it

Comment: That's not how `GROUP BY` works, you probably want two sortings, try with `select * from table order by var1 asc, var2 desc` (will first sort by var1, then by var2)

Comment: Hi all. I have updated by question to show what happens when I try the double order. It doesn't group by the var1. I have added that i'm using phpmyadmin, is that relevant?

Comment: Post a sample of your actual data and expected results.

Comment: Have done forpas. Let me know if still unclear.. I wonder if I should reset phpmyadmin.. it just seems like the answer is so obvious to everyone else..

Comment: For the sample data that you posted this works: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8gFiayqVTvJKomsJ3pUTJh/0

Comment: _“Trying: select * from table order by score desc, url asc doesnt work.”_ - that is the wrong _order_ of ordering. You want to sort your records by url **first**, and then by score second.

Comment: Hi forpas and CBroe, that didn't work for me. It puts facebook above google despite the fact that google has the higher max score (3)

Comment: Of course Facebook does get put first - you said yourself, that you wanted to “group” by the domain _first_, and `f` comes before `g` in the alphabet. I am getting the feeling, that you _still_ not managed to correctly explain, what you actually want here. What you have shown after “so I get:” right now, appears to be the domains sorted by whichever _group_ of domains contains the highest score value. But that does not match your _verbal_ description of what you said you wanted.

Comment: CBroe, happy to admit that I'm not communicating it clearly. I do want to order by whichever group contains the highest score value.

Comment: @scon this is why your question was closed. If you mentioned in your question that you want first the domains with highest score you would get the proper answer. Now edit your question and clarify there and not in the comments.

Comment: Hi @forpas. Happy to add in 'order by whichever group has highest score' to the question. I take it that while you think adding this will get me the proper answer, you don't in fact have that answer.

Comment: Your question is not the most difficult ever asked in SO. I'm confident that if you have explained clearly what you want from the start you would have got already the solution that you need. Whether I have the answer or not is irrelevant because your question is closed.

Answer (score 2):

According to your expected output, you don't need grouping at all, just a multiple column `order by` clause:

```sql
SELECT   *
FROM     mytable
ORDER BY var1 ASC, var2 DESC
```

Comment: Hey Mureinik. I have updated by question to show what happens when I try the double order. It doesn't group by the var1. Not sure what might be going wrong, seems obvious to everyone that what you propose should work.. I have also added that i'm using phpmyadmin, not sure if that's relevant.

Comment: @scon can you please edit your question again and add some sample data and the result you're trying to get for it? Without it, I'm afraid your edit doesn't really explain the issue

Comment: have done. Let me know if still unclear. Can potentially add in more entries/rows..

Answer (score 1):

If i understand, you want order by var1 first as asc and then by var2 as desc.

What about this:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY var1 ASC, var2 DESC;
```

Comment: hey adrainosmateus, as elsewhere noted: i've updated the question for your suggested solution. It's not working for me. Not sure if the fact i'm on phpmyadmin is somehow relevant..