# How do I order groups by each group's highest value

Tags: php, mysql, subquery, sql-order-by, window-functions

I have data:

```
query url score  
a www.google.com 3  
a www.facebook.com 2  
a www.google.com 1
```

I want to 'group' entries by their domain, and then order (desc) the domain groups by each group's highest score so I get:

```
query url score  
a www.google.com 3  
a www.google.com 1
a www.facebook.com 2
```

Trying: select * from table order by score desc, url asc doesnt work. It gives (no apparent change):

```
query url score  
a www.google.com 3  
a www.facebook.com 2  
a www.google.com 1
```

Comment: Go on. Try something.

Comment: Try to order by Score and then order by domain, like this "ORDER BY FIELD1 ASC, FIELD2 ASC"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window functions - if you are running MySQL 8.0:

```
select *
from mytable
order by max(score) over(partition by url) desc, score desc
```

In earlier versions, one option uses a subquery:

```
select *
from mytable t
order by 
    (select max(score) from mytable t1 where t1.url = t.url) desc,
    score desc
```

Comment: Hey @GMB I'm using a mac, my mysql version is 5.7.26 and I only have one table so that second option doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @scon: the second query is what you need. It selects twice from the same table, called `mytable`. Please give it a try.

Comment: Hey @GMB My apologies. Thank you very much (for both your answer and encouraging me to try it), I have been hung-up on this question for a while now. You are champion.