# Can I use substring() on a temporary table variable?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, subquery, sql-order-by

I sort data by each domain-group's highest score using:

```
SELECT * from `Inputs` t 
order by (select max(`score`) from `Inputs` t1 where t1.`domain`=t.`domain`) desc, `score` desc
```

The result is:

```
query domain url score  
a www.google.com www.google.com/a  3  
a www.google.com www.google.com/b  1
a www.facebook.com www.google.com/c 2
```

Rather than storing the domains as well as the url in the database, I would like to instead calculate the domains as a function of the urls within the query using something like:

```
SUBSTRING(`url` from 1 for locate('/',`url` ,10)-1) as `domain`
```

If possible, I would be able to achieve the same ordering of entries (as given above) using one fewer columns:

```
query url score  
a www.google.com/a  3  
a www.google.com/b  1
a www.google.com/c 2
```

Does anyone know how this is achieved if it's possible? I haven't found other questions on stackoverflow about using column aliases for temporary tables.

I have tried nesting another query, without luck:

```
SELECT *, SUBSTRING(`url` from 1 for locate('/',`url` ,10)-1) as `domain` from `Inputs` t
order by (select max(`score`), 
(select SUBSTRING(`url` from 1 for locate('/',`url` ,10)-1) as `domain` from `Inputs` t1 )
 from `Inputs` t1 where t1.`domain`=t.`domain`) asc, `score` asc
```

Comment: Do you really keep asking the SAME question more than once, and accepting (sometimes) an answer, changing the question after being asked, and someone is asking for more info, just start ignoring him?  (ref1: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63202363/can-i-use-column-aliases-in-a-where-clause-equating-temporary-tables?noredirect=1#comment111762012_63202363 ; ref2: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63193038/how-do-i-order-groups-by-each-groups-highest-value/63193108?noredirect=1#comment111746417_63193108)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [substring_Index][1] for this pupose, but you must eventually change the data types or site of CHAR

the  function is actually not needed makes the code more readable

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE Inputs (
  `query` VARCHAR(1),
  `domain` VARCHAR(16),
  `url` VARCHAR(16),
  `score` INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO Inputs
  (`query`, `domain`, `url`, `score`)
VALUES
  ('a', 'www.google.com', 'www.google.com/a', '3'),
  ('a', 'www.google.com', 'www.google.com/b', '1'),
  ('a', 'www.facebook.com', 'www.google.com/c', '2');
  
CREATE FUNCTION geturl (_url CHAR(255))
       RETURNS CHAR(255) DETERMINISTIC
       RETURN SUBSTRING_INDEX(_url, "/", 1);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
select `query`, `domain`, `url` , `score`
from Inputs t
order by 
    (select max(score) from Inputs t1 where geturl(t1.url) = geturl(t.url)) desc,
    score desc;

| query | domain           | url              | score |
| ----- | ---------------- | ---------------- | ----- |
| a     | www.google.com   | www.google.com/a | 3     |
| a     | www.facebook.com | www.google.com/c | 2     |
| a     | www.google.com   | www.google.com/b | 1     |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iGg1g98L9JUioCiDP28bEf/18)

Comment: Hey @nbk. Apologies for confusion. I don't want to create a function, that I then call. i want to combine the original ordering query with the substring() function. I have updated my question to include my attempt at what the code might look like. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: ülease show wjat result you want to get, because i don't what the second order should be.

Comment: The ordering result doesn't change, @nbk. The data I need to hold in my database to achieve that result does (i don't need a domain column to group the entries by because I derive the domain from the urls instead). I have updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: as you noticed you can't do that, besides you sorting something by the max, doesn't work. sorting must be something enumerable, something that can be sorted and a max isn't one of them, so please explain exactly what makes the order this is still very unclear, maybe with another doamin
'

Comment: More info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63193038/how-do-i-order-groups-by-each-groups-highest-value/63193108?noredirect=1#comment111746417_63193108

Comment: I changed my answer, to fit

Comment: Perfect. Thanks @nbk. Apologies for the confusion. This question has been apparently quite confusing (not least of all for its communicator).